# iGraph creating subgraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following problem:
I have the following graph: `g6` which does not include `isolate vertices`. The vertices   are mainly grouped into two `ethnic groups`, given as attribute, namely: `mestizo and   saraguro`.
So I run the `subgraph`option for saraguros as follows:

> g2saraguro <- subgraph(g6, which(V(g6)$ethnic=="saraguro"))
>       summary(g2saraguro)

which did work:

> Vertices: 166
>       Edges: 330
>       Directed: TRUE
>       No graph attributes.
>       Vertex attributes: ii, village, parroquia, canton, provinz, kindR, ethnic,   situation, researcha.
>       Edge attributes: question, activity.

However, if I try the same with `mestizo`, there is a proble, since it just identify:

> s2mestizo <- subgraph(g6,V(g6)$ethnic=="mestizo")
>       summary(s2mestizo)
>       Vertices: 2
>       Edges: 3
>       Directed: TRUE
>       No graph attributes.
>       Vertex attributes: ii, village, parroquia, canton, provinz, kindR, ethnic,   situation, researcha.
>       Edge attributes: question, activity.

but in the reality that is no the case, if I see: `V(g6)$ethnic`, `mestizo` are the  majority `!!`
I really don´t know where the problem is, with `igraph 0.6` the procedure to form a  `subgraph` should be in that or a similar way, without `1-based indexing`.
thanks a lot for any help
regards
Vladimir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use the `which` function in the second case; i.e., instead of

```
s2mestizo <- subgraph(g6,V(g6)$ethnic=="mestizo")
```

you should write

```
s2mestizo <- subgraph(g6, which(V(g6)$ethnic=="mestizo"))
```

Also note that if you are using igraph 0.5.x or earlier, you must subtract 1 from the result of `which` because of the 0-based indexing of igraph. This has been fixed in igraph 0.6 so you don't need to subtract 1 if you are using igraph 0.6 or later.

**Edit**: based on your recent comment, it looks like you are using igraph 0.5.x or earlier (because the output format of `summary` is different for 0.6). In this case, you *must* subtract 1 from the result of `which` because igraph 0.5.x and earlier versions use zero-based vertex indices. Therefore, the correct line should be:

```
s2mestizo <- subgraph(g6, which(V(g6)$ethnic=="mestizo")-1)
```

Comment: Thanks it did work!, this maybe a diffrent question, but I just wonder why R tells that igraph 0.6 was actuallized!?,

Comment: Where or when does R say that it was "actuallized"? I am not even sure what means...

Comment: also sorry, I mean that if I actualize igraph 0.5x to igraph 0.6, R did without any problem, but in this case I still have to substract 1.